# Dynamic Column index as parameter

Tags: excel

First, I know I can do this with some VBA but I don't want to do that.
Been searching the web but haven't come accross a solution to this yet.

So, In excel I use the VLookup-function(I think, excel isn't in english) like so:

```
=LETARAD("key";A2:E65;5;0)
```

This works great.

Now what I want is to make the columnpart dynamic based on what workdate-function returns. Something like this:

```
=LETARAD("key";ColumnIndex(WorkDay("2016-11-30")*7)2:ColumnIndex(WorkDay("2016-11-30")*7)65;5;0)
```

Though I'm unable to achieve this.
Any one got any sugestions? : )

**Solution update:**

This is a simplified version of my solution.
Let's say I have the folowing excelsheet:

```html
<table border="1">
    <tr><td></td><td>A</td><td>B</td><td>C</td><td>D</td><td>E</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>Keys1</td><td>Val</td><td></td><td>Keys2</td><td>Val</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2</td><td>1a</td><td>-5</td><td></td><td>2a</td><td>-3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>3</td><td>1b</td><td>-16</td><td></td><td>2b</td><td>82</td></tr>
    <tr><td>4</td><td>1b</td><td>-19</td><td></td><td>2c</td><td>18</td></tr>
</table>
```

Using the following function I can retreive the values I want.

```
=VLOOKUP("key";INDEX(A2:E4;1;1+((WEEKDAY("2016-11-28")-1)*3)):INDEX(A2:E4;3;2+((WEEKDAY("2016-11-28")-1)*3));2;0)
```

Where key and weekday of course are dynamic and each workday has a set number of keys. The sheet only shows 2 days.
Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In English, you can reference a single column using the `INDEX` function, so

```
=INDEX(A1:C100,,3)
```

References `C1:C100`

Therefore, something like this would work:

```
=VLOOKUP("Key",INDEX(A1:C100,,3),5,0)
```

To change this column each time, you would just need to make the `3` dynamic

*note: you will need to change the `,` to `;` in this example*

Comment: =LETARAD("key";INDEX("A2:E65";;3);5;0) unfortunately gives me value error.

Comment: Sorry - that's my fault actually. Remove the speech marks in the `INDEX` function - I've updated the answer

Comment: Thanks Callum! Figured it out after a while : )